# Openwrt in industrial solutions. connect fail reasons

Tags: openwrt

all,
I have uci wifi setup whitch i know is correct to connect to access point.
But it does not associate sometimes. and other Access point does not connect ever it is equivalent, but with different SSID.
How to  check what is reason for that? "dmesg" does not help too much.

thank You!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `logread` command. Sometimes You can find something in `dmesg` also.